# MySQL insert table and column

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a temp table that is filled from an xml reader, then replaced into the final production table for my site. Right now the columns match, but I would like to add a column to the production table that will be manually updated, and not overridden when we update from the temp table.

Example:
Temp Table has columns:

```
Name
Address
Phone
```

Production Table has:

```
Name 
Address 
Phone
Date
```

Currently I use:

```
REPLACE INTO Tdata select * from temp_Tdata;
```

How do I have it pull in the data from the temp table without changing the current Date column. The tables have over 25 columns so I would prefer not to have to list all of the column names if I can.

Thanks for your help.

UPDATE

```
REPLACE INTO Tdata (Name, Address, Phone) select (Name, Address, Phone) from temp_Tdata;
```

Does not work because the Date column is reset to the default, losing any manual changes that were made to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** Workaround for `REPLACE`

```
REPLACE INTO Tdata (Name, Address, Phone, Date)
SELECT tt.Name, tt.Address, tt.Phone, t.Date
  FROM temp_Tdata tt LEFT JOIN 
       Tdata t ON tt.Name = t.Name;
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b224/1)**

Now you can create a view that brings Date column to temp data

```
CREATE VIEW vw_temp_Tdata
AS
SELECT tt.Name, tt.Address, tt.Phone, t.Date
  FROM temp_Tdata tt LEFT JOIN 
       Tdata t ON tt.Name = t.Name;
```

and then use it like this

```
REPLACE INTO Tdata 
 SELECT * FROM vw_temp_Tdata;
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05a71/1)**

**Original answer** was deleted since it won't work with `REPLACE`.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without have to list out all 25+ column names of the destination table?

Comment: When naming columns from both tables I get

    Operand should contain 1 column(s) Error 1241

Comment: For a view to be updatable, there must be a one-to-one relationship between the rows in the view and the rows in the underlying table.

Comment: Everything works with a view also. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2a206/1. You DO have one-to-one relationship between rows in the view and rows in your table

Comment: I was including the Date column in my replace, opps. Thanks for your help and the fiddles.

Comment: The REPLACE statement won't work because it basically does a DELETE and then an INSERT. So you'll end up with the default value for your Date field. I don't know of a way to solve your problem without specifying all the fields in an UPDATE statement. Sorry!

Comment: @EricImprint See updated answer for a workaround. See if it works for you.

Comment: @Melanie Exactly. Thanks. I almost never use REPLACE myself, so didn't think of that from the beginning.

Comment: Should I use an update or the given replace option with the join?

Comment: @EricImprint My example shows how you can use `REPLACE` in that situation. So try it and let me know how it works for you.

Comment: @EricImprint See updated answer. Made an example of using a view on temp data with `REPLACE` for you.

Comment: @EricImprint DO you need more help with the question?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Tdata
SET Name = temp_TData.Name,
Address = temp_Tdata.Address,
Phone = temp_TData.Phone
WHERE Tdata.Name = temp_Tdata.Name
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without have to list out all 25+ column names of the destination table?

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio, you can drop and drop all column names from the "Object Explorer" into a query window, so you don't have to type all the column names. I don't know if MySQL has a similar capability, but it would probably be worth asking as another question on Stackoverflow

Comment: OK, sorry, you're not doing an INSERT; you're trying to UPDATE data. The REPLACE statement won't work because it basically does a DELETE and then an INSERT. So you'll end up with the default value for your Date field. I don't know of a way to solve your problem without specifying all the fields in an UPDATE statement. Sorry!

Comment: Can you give an example of the UPDATE.

Comment: I don't think the UPDATE's going to help you because you have to specify each field. I've modified my answer above to use UPDATE instead of INSERT so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks for your help. @peterm solution worked better for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to:

1. Add a column to your destination table
2. Insert the data from your original table (which has more columns than the destination table *had*) into your destination table

If that's true, then you need to alter the destination table *before* updating it:

```
ALTER TABLE Tdata
    ADD COLUMN newColumn Varchar(50); -- Just an example
```

Then you can update (or insert) the data.